# C# Unrecognized characters while reading from binary file

Tags: c#

I have some items who's information is split into two parts, one is contents of a binary file, and other is textual entry inside .txt file. I am trying to make an app that will pack this info into one textual file (textual file because I have reasons to want this file to also be humanly readable as well), with ability to later unpack that file back by creating new binary file and text entry.

The first problem I ran into so far: some info is lost when converting binary into string (or perhaps sooner, during reading of bytes), and I'm not sure if the file is in weird format or I'm doing something wrong. Some characters get shown as question marks.

Example of characters which are replaced with question marks:

```
ýÿÿ
```

This is the part where info is read from the binary file and gets encoded into a string (which is how I inteded to store it inside a text file).

```
byte[] binaryFile = File.ReadAllBytes(pathBinary);

// I also tried this for some reason: byte[] binaryFile = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(pathBinary));

string binaryFileText = Convert.ToBase64String(binaryFile); //this is the coded string that goes into joined file to hold binary file information, when decoded the result shows question marks instead of some characters

                    MessageBox.Show("binary file text: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(binaryFile), "debug", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information); //this also shows question marks
```

I expect a few more caveats along the way with second functionality of the app (unpacking back into text and binary), but so far my main problem is unrecognized characters during reading of the binary file or converting it into string, which makes this data unusable in storing as text for purpose of reproducing the file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure they're ascii characters? Have you tried using unicode encoding instead of ascii? Are you even sure it's text data in the binary file?

Comment: Arbitrary binary data is not text, so don't attempt to display it as text.

Comment: Based on your question and the code I suspect that you do not yet know the absolute minimum amount of knowledge necessary to correctly work with text. Start by reading here: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/  As Joel wisely says, **stop writing code until you understand this**.

Comment: You convert your binary file to text in the binaryFileText variable but then in your messagebox.show call you are trying to parse the binary file as ascii. Why have you got two different ways of processing the binary file? Which one are you actually using when creating your text file?

Comment: @Eric Lippert Thanks I'll read that link. But I guess the answer might be, for some reason it is absolutely impossible to store binary data into textual format? Or there is something tricky in particular with this specific type of file?

Comment: @Chris the message box is just a debug to see if I'll get question marks that way as well, the string that would be stored in file is binaryFileText, but that is not relevant for this particular problem.

Comment: @Krafter: If its not relevant you probably shouldn't include it in the question. As it is it appears that you are confused and inconsistent in your attempts to make the binary data into readable text.

Comment: @Krafter You can certainly store binary data in a textual format. In fact, [usenet required people to store all of their binary data in text format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet#Binary_content). It seems like your problem is that your trying to treat binary data *as* text, which is a little different. It's hard to say without you sharing details about the binary file.

Comment: @itsme86 oh ok, well the binary file itself holds a lot of nontextual information and is in ansi encoding when opened in text editor. I am probably having some misconceptions but that is why I need help. Basically the string I got from reading the file bytes in app is different from what I see when opening original binary file in notepad, in that some characters are replaced with question marks, and a new file produced with that string looks wrong in same way when opened in notepad and doesn't work of course. I can provide binary file sample privately if you want to take a look.

Comment: @itsme86 sorry I just realized I might have confused you by saying the product file should be humanly readable. The product file has part that is in common txt and is humanly readable, the rest should be string which is encoded binary file, it is not meant to be readable, I just want it to be stored in same file with readable text part.

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal conversion of binary string data to a string. A string is a series of unicode characters and as such can hold any character of the unicode range.

Binary data is a series of bytes and as such can be anything from video to a string in various formats.

Since there are multiple binary string representations, you need an `Encoding` to convert one into the other. The encoding you choose has to match the binary string format. If it doesn't you will get the wrong result.

You are using ASCII encoding for the conversion, which is obviously incorrect. ASCII can not encode the full unicode range. That means even if you use it for encoding, the result of the decoding will not always match the original text.

If you have both, encoding and decoding under control,  use an `Encoding` that can do the full round trip, such as UTF8 or Unicode. If you don't encode the string yourself, use the correct `Encoding`.

Comment: Thanks I'll think about this. At first the binary file produced by app (and joined txt file) used to be in utf8 encoding so I changed it to ansi but that doesn't helpwith question marks. The part where I want to turn stored string into binary file, it produces a file in ansi encoding but with question marks forsome chars:  byte[] binaryFileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(binaryFileContent); byte[] binaryFileAnsi = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252), binaryFileBytes); File.WriteAllBytes(pathNewBinary, binaryFileAnsi, Encoding.Default); But I think problem starts earlier

Comment: When you write in UTF8, why would you read in ANSI? That's not the same.